# Amp page validating in browser developer console but not on the web interface

Tags: amp-html

https://www.aaa.com/traveltips/rediscover-travel-with-aaa-and-samantha-brown-572099#development=1

This page is validating in the browser developer console:

[image]

But is not validating here: https://validator.ampproject.org/

[image]

Can I assume the page is validating correctly?  Any idea where the disconnect is happening?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The AMP validator has had considerable updates in recent months.

1. Browser console is not accurate at all
2. https://search.google.com/test/amp <--- is 90% correct **[use this!]**
3. Webmaster tools is 100% correct and will find errors the other tools don't

I've had many times where it passes valid AMP and is never indexed due to getting caught with new errors at webmasters final checks. Your code is certainly not valid AMP.

reviewing your code - numerous issues which are definitely blockers to AMP:
You'll need to fix them all.

Also Note - running you page appears to not be loading correctly, so you may also see validation issues because the page you think is displaying isn't... It needs to be available on the internet and not behind a firewall.

Comment: What do you mean by the webmaster tool?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search (formerly called "webmaster tools" - Please consider marking as answered